# Why might a circuit panel have limited capacity on the labels but full capacity in its hardware?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, code-compliance, generator

I am making a breakout box for my portable generator's 120/240 outlet. It is a small [GE Powermax load center](https://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-PowerMark-Plus-125-Amp-8-Space-16-Circuit-Indoor-Main-Lug-Circuit-Breaker-Panel-TLM812FCUDP/202046231) with added outlets in attached metal boxes. (I will be adding the extra ground bar for separate ground and neutral.)

I accidentally ordered the 6/12 version instead of the 8/16 version. Surprisingly to me, the 6/12 version seems to have all the hardware on the buses necessary to support the full 8/16 setup. The only thing that limits to 6/12 (to me) is extra blocking plastic in the bus support panel, and the labeling.

Here are the inside and outside labels, instructing not to use positions 7 & 8, the lower left two positions:

[image: front label]

[image: inside label]

Here are the bus bars:

[image: bus bars 1]

[image: bus bars 2]

Those bus bars look complete to me.

Here are the extra plastic blockers on the breaker supports, blocking positions 7 & 8:

[image: blocking plastic]

FWIW both the 6/12 and 8/16 are 125 Amp panels.

So the manufacturer had to come up with a special plastic support and special labels, and not screw up by accidentally inserting them in the run of 8/16's, so as to limit what appears to be a fully functional device.

Though we cannot perhaps ask the manufacturer, is there any reason that the manufacturer would intentionally hobble the device so it cannot be used to its full potential?

Answer (score 4):

Who knows? Ask UL.  Could be the neutral bars aren't big enough, or they had a production issue and were forced to improvise.

What is the case, however, is that model is listed for 6 spaces not 8, and so it is not UL listed for 8 spaces.

Per 110.3(B) you cannot modify the panel.  I would take it back and get the 8-space.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is marketing. They position the price of the limited version to compete with some other manufacturer. If you want the full feature you have to pay for it.

Kind of like tethering computer to phone for internet. Almost all phones are capable of it, some carriers limit which plans are allowed to do it.